# FOR LOOP IN PL/SQL BLOCK

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Please let me know how to get 'AA' 'BB' 'CC' from below query

```
declare
   type arrays1 is varray(3) of varchar2(30);
   a1 arrays1 := arrays1('A', 'B', 'C');
   type arrays2 is varray(3) of varchar2(30);
   a2 arrays2 := arrays2('A', 'B', 'C');
begin
   for i in 1..a1.count loop
      for j in 1..a2.count loop
         insert into dummy_insert  values(concat(a1(i),a2(j)));
         commit;
      end loop;
   end loop;
end;
```

Now I am getting 9 rows

Comment: Don't yell. The title is already in bold and of a larger size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Now I am getting 9 rows"

The outer loop steps through an array of three elements.  The nested loop steps through an array of three elements for every element in the outer loop.  3 * 3 = 9.

> "how to get 'AA' 'BB' 'CC' from below query"

Apply Occam's razor and discard the inner loop:

```
declare
   type arrays1 is varray(3) of varchar2(30);
   a1 arrays1 := arrays1('A', 'B', 'C');
begin
   for i in 1..a1.count loop
         insert into dummy_insert  values(concat(a1(i),a1(i)));
   end loop;
   commit;
end;
```

Please note that committing inside loops is bad practice.  Obviously it doesn't make any difference with a toy piece of code like this, but if we always do the right thing we won't do the wrong thing when it actually matters.

Comment: Did you mean `concat(a1(i), a1(i))`?

Comment: @BobJarvis - of course I meant that.  Well spotted!

Comment: You've removed the second array. If removing stuff like that is an acceptable answer, why not just change the entire code to `begin insert into dummy_insert values ('AA'); insert into dummy_insert values ('BB'); insert into dummy_insert values ('CC'); commit; end;` ... :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - frankly I agree with you, but I think it's a toy question.  My assumption remains that the OP is learning about Arrays, and therefore my solution is valid (and the opening paragraph is even helpful) whereas a pure SQL solution would not be instructive.  I suspect Alex's solution is more likely to have applications in the real world.

Answer (score 2):

You could just test that the values are the same:

```
...
  for i in 1..a1.count loop
    for j in 1..a2.count loop
      if a1(i) = a2(j) then
        insert into dummy_insert values(concat(a1(i),a2(j)));
      end if;
    end loop;
  end loop;
...
```

(Seems kind of pointless, but without any idea what you real-world situation is it's hard to advise how to improve the logic.)